# Hiding an element after another is clicked through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few elements with the same class 'showFaq'.  I would like to make it so I can only open one element in the 'showFaq' class at a time.

```
 $(".subFaq").hide();
 $(".showFaq").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".subFaq").hide();
$(".showFaq").click(function(){
    $(".subFaq").hide(); // hide all the faq before showing the current one
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a parent of the FAQ's first, and then

```
$(".showFaq").click(function(){
     $('#parent').children().filter(':not(this)').hide();
}
```

haven't tested but hopefully it will work